# Dialog fragment is not showing a view in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I'm using androidx dialog fragment to show some content but it is not showing the dialog view.
My code is

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/content_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_10">

                //my design
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of ConstraintLayout. This problem can be solved by making the constraint layout as a child of RelativeLayout.

Note: If you use LinearLayout as parent for ConstraintLayout then it won't work.

#bst